# What is the group $\Gamma$ such that $\mathbb{H}/\Gamma$ is a genus-n torus

Tags: algebraic-topology, hyperbolic-geometry, fundamental-groups

We know that the universal cover of genus-n torus is a unit disk ($n\ge2$), which is conformal to upper half plane $\mathbb{H}$, with automorphism group $SL(2,\mathbb{R})$. Thus the genus-n torus can be identified with $\mathbb{H}/\Gamma$. with $\Gamma$ isomorphic to the fundamental group of genus-n torus. I want to know the exact form how $\Gamma$ embedded in $SL(2,\mathbb{R})$.

Comment: Do you mean you want to have exact matrix coefficients of generators of $\Gamma$? (There was a recent question on MSE asking for this.) Incidentally, topologists call this not "genus g torus" but "genus g surface".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very explicit (and completely useless in my opinion) computation of 2-by-2 matrices for a genus $g$ surface could be found on pages 183-184 of

Dubrovin, Novikov, Fomenko, "Modern Geometry: Methods and Applications: The Geometry and Topology of Manifolds. Part 2", Springer-Verlag, Graduate Texts in Mathematics, Volume 93.

Answer (score 0):

First, the group of orientation-preserving isometries of the upperhalf plane is not $SL(2,R)$ but rather $PSL(2,R)$. Second, this surface is not called a genus-$n$ torus but rather a genus-$n$ surface; the term *torus* is generally reserved for the genus-$1$ case.

So what you are asking for is an explicit Fuchsian group of a closed surface of genus $n$. These are not that easy to exhibit explicitly. One approach is to use congruence subgroups using suitable quaternion algebras, as developed [here](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0505007).

Sometimes it is best to "construct" these groups geometrically using fundamental domains in the upperhalf plane. This shows the "existence" of the groups without exhibiting them explicitly. I also recommend the book by S. Katok on Fuchsian groups.